# Javascript на android

Tags: javascript, css

Хотелось бы узнать может кто то знает самоучитель html,css или javascript на android?
Поделитесь,пожалуйста

P.S не "под" android,а что бы его можно было скачать на android

Comment: HTML,CSS,JS "должны" себя вести одинаково на windows, android, mac os, или Linux. Используйте любой самоучитель по этим языкам, а со временем уже сами поймете особенности верстки под андройдовский webkit или opera mobile

Comment: >не "под" android,а что бы его можно было скачать на android

вы хотите сказать, что не можете найти книг по html+css+js? По-моему их навалом.

Answer (score 1):

html+css: http://htmlbook.ru
javascript: http://learn.javascript.ru/

"на андроид" не нужно ничего скачивать. Нужно установить себе на комп и развернуть вот это: http://phonegap.com/
И учиться, учиться, учиться...